# PHP regex for exploding email receivers

Tags: php, regex, explode

In my SQL, I have some rows that contain email senders. Those senders are strings and not separated via columns.

This is 1 example from my row.

```
"Test Example" <test@example.com>, "Second Person" <sperson@example.com>, third@example.com
```

As you can see, it's plain text and ready for explode. I can explode it with comma and separate them.

But today I realized this example:

```
"Test, Example" <test@example.com>, "Second Person" <sperson@example.com>, third@example.com
```

As you see, Test has a comma in its name. So if I explode it, it will explode Test too. This will cause an error.

I tried some regex but with no luck. Could anyone suggest to me the best regex to explode them but not names?

FYI, names always in **""** tag. So commas are not.

I simply need to pass if **comma** is in **quotes**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
explode('>, "', $emails);
```

And add the exploded chars afterwards - or, better yet, use [`imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-rfc822-parse-adrlist.php).

Comment: +1 for `imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist()`. Probably the best way for doing this.

Comment: I like the `imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist()` solution, but the explode isn't a good idea. If there are spaces between `>` and `,` it won't work.

Comment: @ColinHebert: FTR, I don't like it either. I just figured if there's a good solution already I shouldn't waste much of my time with a edgy one. The OP should definitively use `imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist`.

Comment: Thanks to everyone! imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist is what i need! Good to know that. Answer is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should be validating your data into the database, so someone's name cannot contain a "," (or other symbols as well).

You dont want your users dictating your formatting display, you should format the text yourself when you need to display it